# Cross Join in Entity framework Lambda Expressions

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

How can I do the following join in EF?
Tables have no relation with each other, no foreign keys.

```
Select t1.ID,  t1.firstname, t2.ID,t2.name from MY_TEST_TABLE1 t1, MY_TEST_TABLE2 t2
where t1.firstname = t2.name
```

Comment: That query doesn't have an `outer join`...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You could do this:

```
var query= from t1 in context.MY_TEST_TABLE1
           from t2 in context.MY_TEST_TABLE2
           where t1.firstname == t2.name
           select new { Table1Id= t1.ID, FirstName= t1.firstname, Table2Id=t2.ID,Name= t2.name};
```

Another way to do a cross join in Linq to Entities is using [SelectMany](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb548748(v=vs.110).aspx) extension method:

```
var query= context.MY_TEST_TABLE1.SelectMany(
    t1=>context.MY_TEST_TABLE2
        .Where(t2=>t1.firstname == t2.name)
        .Select(t2=>new { 
            Table1Id= t1.ID,
            FirstName= t1.firstname, 
            Table2Id=t2.ID,
            Name= t2.name
        })
    );
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this:

```
var results = from t1 in dbcontext.my_test_table1s
              join t2 in dbcontext.my_test_table2s on t1.firstname equals t2.name
              select new 
              { 
                   t1id = t1.Id, 
                   firstname = t1.firstname, 
                   t2id = t2.id, 
                   name = t2.name 
              };
```